# update multiple objects in parse cloud code

Tags: database, parse-platform, cloud

I am new to Parse and am in need of guidance. I have a game where users gain points from other users they brought in, so if A brought in B who brought in C, A would get points for the progress of both B and C respectively. I want to call a parse cloud code function every time a user completes a level so that the entire tree he is connected to can gain points as well. This has proven to be very costly, and very complicated. Are there any best practice suggestions or possible solutions for a problem like this?

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a flattened list of users that need to receive points when a certain user completes a level, together with a ratio. For example:

```
(B, A, 100)
(C, A, 50)
(C, B, 100)
```

under the assumption that `A` would receive fewer points from `C` because of the indirect relationship. [Relations](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#relations) might be the abstraction you need.

If `C` brings in `D`, then you need to add

```
(D, A, 25)
(D, B, 50)
(D, C, 100)
```

This should have the advantage that you only need to do these computations when the user graph changes, as opposed to every time a level is played. On a level completion, you only need to make a single query.

When a user is deleted, it might be sufficient to remove the rows that contain that user.